# How to open a photoshop file in CS6 from CS4

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, graphics

How can I open a file from CS4 in CS6. Do I have to convert? export? or how do I save it in CS4 so I can open it in CS6?

Comment: I just select `File > Open > file.psd` and it works fine... are you experiencing issues with this or are you asking before making the switch?

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop files are generally backward compatible. This backward compatibility is especially maintained if you check the `Maximize Compatibility` option on save.

[image: Maximize Compatibility]

If there is a problem with one specific Photoshop file you have, we'd be happy to help you open and save that file if you edit your question to include the file and what you've already tried.

Welcome to SuperUser, by the way!